Chrome Print to PDF via Windows Command Prompt
I'm trying to print a webpage to a PDF and it's not working as of this week. I'm using Chrome, but it's also not working with Edge.
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --headless --print-to-pdf="new_file.pdf" "https://google.com"

Can anyone help please?

Try using --headless=old
My reasoning: As of 9/2/2024, the chromium/new-headless page contains these three statements:

To use new Headless mode, pass the --headless=new command-line flag:
chrome --headless=new


For now, the old Headless mode is still available with:
chrome --headless=old


Passing the --headless command-line flag without an explicit value still activates the old Headless mode, but we intend to change this default.

Based on problems that we had last week, and on other people reporting recent headless issues, I suspect that the Chromium team recently changed that default.  In particular, I see Issue 362301064: Headless print-to-pdf is no longer functional unless headless=old, which seems to match the issue we're all having.  I haven't had a chance to try it yet in our code, but I expect this to fix it.

Chromium's such as MS Edge and Chrome etc. will not be able to use --headless=old for much longer, it was supposed to be removed by the default set to the newer mode.
It is the conflict between a new session in memory that causes the current mis-match needing a headless session to be set to older methods. and the recommendation for moving forwards when using a headless print-to-PDF is to use the faster lighter shell version.
To see how to very simply download a dedicated set of LATEST STABLE files in Windows (for migration) refer to the download script at Chromium based MSEdge or Chrome Headless Printing Exit Code 21
copied here for convenience.
Helper script to download and unpack latest stable version. You will need to adjust first 2 lines for 64bit (=chrome-headless-shell-win64.zip & =win64/%download%).
headless-shell.cmd
set "download=chrome-headless-shell-win32.zip"
set "variant=win32/%download%"

curl -o LATEST_RELEASE_STABLE.txt https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/LATEST_RELEASE_STABLE
set /p version=<LATEST_RELEASE_STABLE.txt
curl -O https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/%version%/%variant%
tar -xf %download%

Result will be an unpacked folder that can be overwritten as required by rerun the script.
